# How to make #include <stuff> to be highlighted as keywords?

Tags: listings, highlighting, keywords, syntax-highlighting

I have the following snippet of code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% Solarized colors
\definecolor{sbase03}{HTML}{002B36}
\definecolor{sbase02}{HTML}{073642}
\definecolor{sbase01}{HTML}{586E75}
\definecolor{sbase00}{HTML}{657B83}
\definecolor{sbase0}{HTML}{839496}
\definecolor{sbase1}{HTML}{93A1A1}
\definecolor{sbase2}{HTML}{EEE8D5}
\definecolor{sbase3}{HTML}{FDF6E3}
\definecolor{syellow}{HTML}{B58900}
\definecolor{sorange}{HTML}{CB4B16}
\definecolor{sred}{HTML}{DC322F}
\definecolor{smagenta}{HTML}{D33682}
\definecolor{sviolet}{HTML}{6C71C4}
\definecolor{sblue}{HTML}{268BD2}
\definecolor{scyan}{HTML}{2AA198}
\definecolor{sgreen}{HTML}{859900}
\definecolor{myolive}{rgb}{0.51, 0.59, 0.0}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    % How/what to match
    sensitive=true,
    % Border (above and below)
    frame=tlbr,
    framesep=2pt, % frame border width
    framerule=0pt,% frame border line width
    % Extra margin on line (align with paragraph)
    xleftmargin=\parindent,
    % Put extra space under caption
    belowcaptionskip=1\baselineskip,
    % Colors
    backgroundcolor=\color{sbase3},
    basicstyle=\color{sbase00}\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\color{myolive},
    commentstyle=\color{sbase1},
    stringstyle=\color{sblue},
    numberstyle=\color{sviolet}\tiny,
    identifierstyle=\color{sbase02},
    % Break long lines into multiple lines?
    breaklines=true,
    % Show a character for spaces?
    showstringspaces=false,
    tabsize=2
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
% we need to define this because otherwise listings won't
% pick up style changes
\newfontface\UMono[Scale=MatchUppercase]{UbuntuMono}

\makeatletter
\lst@InstallKeywords k{attributes}{attributestyle}\slshape{attributestyle}{}ld
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{cpp}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\fontsize{7}{7}\UMono,
  alsoletter={\#}, % doesn't work
  moreattributes={main,\#include}, % #include doesn't work
  attributestyle = \color{sblue},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=cpp]
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y){
  return x + y;
}

int main(){
  int a = add(1,3);
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Which renders the following:

[image]

I would like to make `#include <stuff>` (and `#include "stuff.h"`) to be of different color/treated as different type of keyword.

The closest I have come to this is to use:

```
literate={\#include}{{\textcolor{sorange}{\#include}}}7,
```

in my style definition but it only colors `#include`.

[image]

How can I achieve that? I use `luatex` if that matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a new line comment style for all lines starting with `#`. The style format then is applied up to the end of the line. The relevant changes to your document are:

```
\lstdefinestyle{cpp}{
  language=C++,
  basicstyle=\fontsize{7}{7}\UMono,
  alsoletter={\#}, % doesn't work
  moreattributes={main},              % <-- Here
  morecomment=[l][\color{scyan}]{\#}, % <-- and here
  attributestyle = \color{sblue},
}
```

In a slightly modified sample code it looks like this (please ignore the fact that I don't have your font installed on my system):

[image]

Also note that using `#` as an operator in your code (not sure this is even allowed in C++) would make the rest of the line be highlighted as if it were a preprocessor pragma. I don't know a workaround for that other than using a different symbol and making it look like a `#` via the `literate` key.

Comment: I don't think you can use `#` as an operator in C++. Anyway, if that were the case and someone is using it, they will deserve the consequences...